BigQuery SQL struggling to add a 'group by' command:
I have data that is one row per account number per month, with a column for account balance.
I want to identify each month how many customers have had a balance >0 for 3 consecutive months, in BigQuery.
I have this code that works to create 'OD_USER', a 0/1 indicator to indicate if a positive balance or not each month.
SELECT 
 EXTRACT(Month from Date) AS TDATE,
   ACCOUNT_ID,
   BALANCE,
    CASE WHEN BALANCE >0 THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 END AS OD_USER
 FROM  `monthly_performance` 
ORDER BY ACCOUNT_ID, TDATE

I want to summarise for each month how many accounts have either 0,1,2 or 3 as values for RU_IND,
where RU_IND is a count of the number of positive balance across the current month plus month before and after. I wrote this line of code to define RU_IND:
SUM(OD_USER) OVER(ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS RU_IND

... but this code wouldn't distinguish between different account numbers...
Also as far as I can tell, BigQuery doesn't have CALCULATED as a command, so I have to use a sub-query logic for my sql code to recognise OD_USER?
And then I need to summarise with GROUP BY TDATE / RU_IND...?
I want to do this in one sql step, without creating any table...
Expecting output as this (unique account numbers counted):



month
SUM_0
SUM_1
SUM_2
SUM_3




1
100
200
300
400


2
150
150
350
350


3
etc...






Thanks for any help, I'd love to know how to do this!

What's wrong with a subquery? SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ...AS OD_USER FROM ...) AS calc

Add partition by account_id to SUM(OD_USER) OVER(ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS RU_IND

Thanks Charlieface / ValNik. Partition, yes thanks makes sense. No nothing wrong with a subquery, I'm just a bit of an sql novice and i can write the subquery but then when i try to group by date and ru_ind I get errors so I'm not sure how to do it...

THIS IS MY BEST CODE:

SELECT
SUM(OD_USER) OVER(PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_ID ORDER BY TDATE ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS RU_IND
FROM
(
SELECT
ACCOUNT_ID,
EXTRACT(Month from Date) AS TDATE,
CASE WHEN OVERDRAFT_BALANCE >0 THEN 1
ELSE 0 END AS OD_USER
FROM  analytics-take-home-test.monzo_borrowing.monthly_performance  as tstats)
GROUP BY TDATE, RU_IND

Column RU_IND contains an analytic function, which is not allowed in GROUP BY at [11:18]

See example.
1.Count month with balance>0 for each account_id, current,previous and next (RU_IND). RU_IND is 0,1,2 or 3, calculated for each month
2.Count separately accounts with RU_IND=0,RU_IND=1,RU_IND=2,RU_IND=3,
SELECT Tyear,tmonth 
  ,count(*) total_accounts
  ,sum(case when ru_ind=0 then 1 else 0 end)sum_0
  ,sum(case when ru_ind=1 then 1 else 0 end)sum_1
  ,sum(case when ru_ind=2 then 1 else 0 end)sum_2
  ,sum(case when ru_ind=3 then 1 else 0 end)sum_3
FROM ( 
  SELECT ACCOUNT_ID
    ,EXTRACT(Month from Date) AS Tmonth,EXTRACT(year from Date) AS Tyear
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN BALANCE >0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
         OVER(PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_ID ORDER BY DATE 
              ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING) 
      AS RU_IND 
  FROM monthly_performance as tstats
  ) 
  -- filter is here, if necessary
where tYear=2024 and Tmonth=4 -- where tYear=@y and Tmonth=@m
GROUP BY Tyear,tmonth 
order by Tyear,tmonth

For month=4 we have result



account_id
tmonth
tyear
ru_ind




1
4
2024
3


2
4
2024
2


3
4
2024
1



Grouping result is (for month=4)



tyear
tmonth
total_accounts
sum_0
sum_1
sum_2
sum_3




2024
4
3
0
1
1
1



Test data
create table monthly_performance (Account_id int,Date date,BALANCE float);
insert into monthly_performance values
 (1,'2024-01-01',100)
,(1,'2024-02-01',100)
,(1,'2024-03-01',100)
,(1,'2024-04-01',100)
,(1,'2024-05-01',100)
,(2,'2024-01-01',100)
,(2,'2024-02-01',-100)
,(2,'2024-03-01',-100)
,(2,'2024-04-01',100)
,(2,'2024-05-01',100)
,(3,'2024-03-01',-100)
,(3,'2024-04-01',-100)
,(3,'2024-05-01',100)
,(3,'2024-06-01',100)
,(3,'2024-07-01',100)
;  

Fiddle

wow thanks so much ValNik, amazing help, really appreciate!!!
